Unnecessary space in gb4e gloss after \eachwordtwo redefining and page layout reformatting
I have an interlinear linguistic gloss using gb4e and in order to make it tidy, I reformatted the page layout according to my writing requirement using geometry and I reproduced Alan Munn's code, where Alan redefined the spacing format in the \eachwordtwo function, so that there are spaces in between the lines of the gloss. I did a little modification to accommodate my three lines gloss, and here is my tex document:
%okegas yuk bisa yuk

\documentclass{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{anything}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=3cm,
 right=3cm,
 top=3cm,
 bottom=3cm
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
 
\let\eachwordone=\it
 
\noautomath
\setlength{\glossglue}{2pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\renewcommand{\eachwordthree}{\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}}

 \ex %Glosa 2
 {\bf (Strategi susunan kalimat)}
 \glll \?{в} \?{результате} \?{рейдов} \?{по} \?{поиску} \?{геев} \?{в} \?{Чечне} \?{около} \?{40} \?{человек} \?{пропали} \?{и} \?{до} \?{20} \?{были} \?{убиты} \textnormal{[$\emptyset$\textsc{agn.}$\emptyset$\textsc{v}]}: \?{их} \?{тела} \?{якобы} \?{«}\textnormal{[$\emptyset$\textsc{agn.}$\emptyset$\textsc{s}]} \?{закапывают} \?{в} \?{лесу»} \\
v rezul'tat-e rejd-ov po poisk-u ge-ev v čečn-e okolo 40 čelovek prola-l-i i do 20 by-l-i ubit-y-$\emptyset$ [$\emptyset$\textsc{agn.}$\emptyset$\textsc{v}]: ix tel-a jakoby “[$\emptyset$\textsc{agn.}$\emptyset$\textsc{s}] zaka-pyva-jut v les-u" \\
pada hasil\textsc{-prep} serangan\textsc{-jam.gen} melalui pencarian\textsc{-dat} gay\textsc{-jam.gen} di Chechnya\textsc{-prep} sekitar 40 orang\textsc{.jam.gen} hilang\textsc{-lamp-jam.intrs} dan hingga 20 menjadi\textsc{-lamp-jam} tewas\textsc{-jam-pend.part.pas} \textsc{impr}: mereka\textsc{-3jam.pos} tubuh\textsc{-jam.nom} menurut-dugaan\textsc{.adv} “\textsc{per.tdf} dikubur\textsc{-impf-3jam} di hutan\textsc{-lok}" \\
 \trans “Akibat operasi pencarian kelompok gay di Chechnya, sekitar 40 orang menghilang dan 20 lainnya dibunuh: tubuh mereka diduga ‘dikubur di hutan’” \\

\end{exe}                   

\end{document}

However, the resulting tex document results in an unnecessary space between the translation and the metalinguistic gloss, as shown here in the typeset below:

I have tried to modify the \setlength{\glossglue}{2pt plus 2pt minus 1pt} but it does not provide a uniform formatting; some of the glosses are in fact okay, they do not contain the unnecessary space, like this gloss below:

Is there any way so that the document does not results in unnecessary spacing? I would like my document to uniformly have no spacing like the picture hereinabove.

it looks as if spaces at the end of lines matter, if you remove the spaces before the \\  it works better (\?{лесу»}\\ etc).

Thank you @UlrikeFischer, it works!
